# How to increment value within a <a> tag

Tags: javascript, html, increment

Hi I want to increment the value within an  and increment it by 1 every time a button is clicked. The code i have so far is shown below:

```
<a data-role="button" data-icon="shop" class="ui-btn-right ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-center ui-icon-heart" id="Count" style="text-align: center;">0</a>

<script>


btn.onclick = function() {
  var linkText = parseInt(document.getElementById('Count').value);
  value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
  value++;
  document.getElementById('Count').value = value;
  }
</script>
```

however it does not update the value of `<a></a>` once I press the button. I want to be able to change the value of `<a>` tag for example `<a>0</a>` and once the button is pressed `<a>` tag will display `<a>1</a>`

Comment: How's `btn` defined? Any console errors?

Comment: no errors are displayed here is how my actual code for button looks like. code updated

Comment: To access the text of anchor tag use `innerHTML`, `innerText` or `textContent` instead of `value` . Use `btn.onclick = function() {
  var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('Count').innerHTML);
  value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
  value++;
  document.getElementById('Count').innerHTML = value;
}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `textContent` instead of `value`, which is a property reserved for input elements.

```js
var count = document.getElementById('Count');

document.getElementById('button').onclick = function() {
  var linkText = +count.textContent;

  count.textContent = ++linkText;
}
```

```html
<button id="button">Increment</button>

<a data-role="button" id="Count">0</a>
```

Comment: thanks this code managed to fix it.